# Why are some annotations semi transparent, while others are not

Tags: pdf, evince, transparency, annotation

When viewing pdfs using Evince, I have noticed that some Annotations (see picture) are transparent (left one), while others are not (right one).

- Why is that?
- Is there a settings to tweak to remove that?
- Or is that a pdf-format related "feature" and there is nothing evince can do about it ?

[image showing the difference between two annotations beeing different](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CoK8K.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.